# Can a virtual drive written as a minifilter driver read and write from a sql server database?

Tags: kernel, driver, minifilter

I need to create a virtual drive where the entire file and directory tree, and more importantly - the permissions, are written in a sql server database. So, whenever a user opens a folder or a file on this virtual drive, the driver will query the database and create the folder's content from the results.

My question is: can kernel mode drivers access a user mode service such as sql server?

Answer (score 0):

Kernel mode drivers can communicate with user-mode components, but the user-mode component needs to be designed to deal with this. So I can't think of a way for a driver to directly call SQL server, but a driver designed by you could communicate with a service designed by you, which would perform SQL queries, and return results to the driver.

The [FltSendMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544378(v=vs.85).aspx) API is probably a good place to start learning about this.